# PHP Script Stalls At oci_execute

Tags: php, oracle10g

I have a script with the following code to insert data into an Oracle table:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_TABLE (ID, FIELD, VAL) VALUES (:id, :test, :ok)"; 

$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
//die("parsed ok");

oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":id", $id);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":test", $test);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":ok", $ok);

//die("params bound");

$result =@oci_execute($stid);

if(!$result)
{               
   $err = oci_error($stid);
   $error = $err['message']; 
   echo $error; die('end error');
}

echo oci_num_rows($stid) . " rows inserted.<br />";
die("inserted");
```

The script was working fine, and then it just stopped.  I threw in some die statements to find where the script is stalling.  The last place I can get to is "die("params bound")".

I've verified that the variables are ok and that the database connection is valid.  I also manually connected to the database using sqldeveloper and had no problem.

Why is this script suddenly stalling?

Comment: What if you remove the silence operator (`@`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As often happens, I had a though immediately after I posted this question.  I checked to see how many connections I had open in a GUI, and then closed the connections.

It turns out that I had some uncommitted changes from some queries that I ran manually in my GUI, and I think that was stalling the script at oci_execute.  After rolling back the changes and restarting my connection, the script works fine now.